# How to change element's specific children attributes and content after cloning

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, nodechildren

I've been reading several questions that appear to be similar but didn't find one that resolve my issue or that the suggested solution solved my problem

I have the following html:

```
<div id="template">
    <div class="section1" id="sec1">                
        <div class="content">
            <img id="sec1-is" *ngIf="!tstEnded" src="assets/images/r1.png" srcset="assets/images/r1@2x.png 2x,assets/images/r1@3x.png 3x" >
            <img id="sec1-if" *ngIf="tstEnded" src="assets/images/r2.png" srcset="assets/images/r2@2x.png 2x,assets/images/r2@3x.png 3x" />
            <div class="audio-controls">
                <button *ngIf="do1()" (click)="act1()" class="control-btn r1-btn" [ngClass]="{'disabled':!r1Enabled()}"></button>
                <button *ngIf="do2()" (click)="act2()" class="control-btn r2-btn" [ngClass]="{'disabled':!r2Enabled()}"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="test-wrapper">
                <span class="test-line">
                    {{eta}}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="test-wrapper">
                <div class="test" tst testType="R" (tstGo)="go($event)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </div>                  
    <div class="section2" id="sec2" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #d0f6f6, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));">
        <div class="content">
            <div *ngIf="ended">         
                <img *ngIf="!open" class="case1" (click)="case1()" src="assets/images/case1c.svg" />
                <img *ngIf="open" class="case1" src="assets/images/case1.svg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After cloning the `template` I wish to change the `id` attribute of section 1 and 2 as well as the `src` and `srcset` of `section1` images `sec1-is` & `sec1-if`
and change the

```
let itm = document.getElementById("template");
let cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
```

How can I get a specific "nested" element without iterating over all the children and grandchildren of `template`, searching for the correct tag?

Comment: cln.setAttribute("id-to-obj", "2949019043"); or change id-to-obj to whatever you want? I'd ID the element and keep it on record some how? :) Adjusted answer to give a better idea, you can then querySelector based on the attribute, that's a different question or easy search. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help:

```js
    var origin, clone, item;
    origin = document.getElementById("template");
    clone = origin.cloneNode(true);
    item = clone.querySelector("#sec1");
    item.setAttribute("id", "sec2");
```

Overall:
Use `querySelector` on your `clone` then `setAttribute` to update.

Since your `img` already has `id` so you can query directly with `#sec1-is`.

But in general, with `querySelector` you can have the query string like `#sec1 img`. Similar to css selector

You can learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: thanks! this changes the attribute values in clone. Unfortunately the ngif and (click) of `clone` don't work. any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the specific using `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` from the cloned element.

**Demo:**

```js
let itm = document.getElementById("template");
let cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
//get element with .section1
let section1 = cln.querySelector('.section1');
//set id
section1.id = 'sec123'
console.log(section1);
//get element with img in .section1
let img = section1.querySelectorAll('.content img');
//set src of first image
img[0].src = '../test';
//set srcset of first image
img[0].srcset = '../test/test';
console.log(img[0]);
//set src of second image
img[1].src = '../test2';
//set srcset of second image
img[1].srcset = '../test2/test';
console.log(img[1]);
```

```html
<div id="template">
    <div class="section1" id="sec1">                
        <div class="content">
            <img id="sec1-is" *ngIf="!tstEnded" src="assets/images/r1.png" srcset="assets/images/r1@2x.png 2x,assets/images/r1@3x.png 3x" >
            <img id="sec1-if" *ngIf="tstEnded" src="assets/images/r2.png" srcset="assets/images/r2@2x.png 2x,assets/images/r2@3x.png 3x" />
            <div class="audio-controls">
                <button *ngIf="do1()" (click)="act1()" class="control-btn r1-btn" [ngClass]="{'disabled':!r1Enabled()}"></button>
                <button *ngIf="do2()" (click)="act2()" class="control-btn r2-btn" [ngClass]="{'disabled':!r2Enabled()}"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="test-wrapper">
                <span class="test-line">
                    {{eta}}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="test-wrapper">
                <div class="test" tst testType="R" (tstGo)="go($event)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </div>                  
    <div class="section2" id="sec2" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #d0f6f6, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));">
        <div class="content">
            <div *ngIf="ended">         
                <img *ngIf="!open" class="case1" (click)="case1()" src="assets/images/case1c.svg" />
                <img *ngIf="open" class="case1" src="assets/images/case1.svg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the ngif and (click) of cln don't work. any Ideas?